# text after code block in beamer

Tags: org-mode, org-export, beamer

I want to use org to make a Beamer slide like this:

```
 --------------------------------
|                                |
|   some text                    |
|                                |
|   --------------------         |
|  |  code              |        |
|   --------------------         |
|                                |
|   more text                    |
|                                |
 --------------------------------
```

But if I attempt this in org-mode, like the following:

```
* More Complex Example
  some text

*** library.py         :B_block:
    #+begin_src python
    code
    #+end_src

  more text
```

...the output looks like this:

```
 --------------------------------
|                                |
|   some text                    |
|                                |
|   --------------------         |
|  |  code              |        |
|  |  more text         |        |
|   --------------------         |
|                                |
|                                |
 --------------------------------
```

How do I put `more text` on the same slide, but outside of the code block?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a "closing" heading:

```
***                                                       :B_ignoreheading:
:PROPERTIES:
:BEAMER_env: ignoreheading
:END:
```

Hence, your example should look like this:

```
* More Complex Example
  some text

*** library.py         :B_block:
    #+begin_src python
    code
    #+end_src
***                                                       :B_ignoreheading:
:PROPERTIES:
:BEAMER_env: ignoreheading
:END:

more text
```

See https://github.com/fniessen/refcard-org-beamer#end-of-block.

Comment: I speculated that I needed some way of making an "invisible" heading but didn't know what to search for.  This works, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It's a pity that it's not mentioned in the manual nor in the tutorial, since it's a more natural mapping of constructs from org to beamer, but you can use special org blocks (avoiding the boilerplate of subsectioning with its drawers and everything) as defined [here](https://orgmode.org/manual/Special-blocks-in-LaTeX-export.html#Special-blocks-in-LaTeX-export). For example:

```
Some text...

#+BEGIN_theorem
...
#+END_theorem

...text continues here
```

Then you may prefer to use subsections only for columns or nested structure and blocks for simple "boxes" in your frame.

You can also alter the AST tree a bit if you prefer:

```
#+BEGIN_theorem Hahn-Banach
...
#+END_theorem
```

to

```
#+ATTR_LATEX :options [Hahn-Banach]
#+BEGIN_theorem
...
#+END_theorem
```

Here is a generic filter that will honour `#+ATTR_xxx` in case it's present for the current backend but will default to the argument of the special block otherwise:

```
(defun my-org-special-block-filter (tree backend _symbol)
  (pcase-let ((`(,prop ,fmt)
               (cond ((org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'latex)
                      '(:attr_latex ":options %s")))))
    (when prop
      (org-element-map tree 'special-block
        (lambda (element)
          (unless (org-element-property prop element)
            (save-excursion
              (goto-char (org-element-property :begin element))
              (when (looking-at "[ \t]*#\\+begin_\\S-+[ \t]+\\([^\n]+\\)")
                (let ((attr (format fmt (match-string-no-properties 1))))
                  (org-element-put-property element prop (list attr))))))
          nil)))))
```

Finally, you can add some font locking to highlight semantically relevant items. As a starter:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'org-mode
  '(("[ \t]*\\(#\\+\\(BEGIN\\|END\\)_\\(\\S-+\\)\\)[ \t]*\\([^\n:]*\\)"
     (1 '(:foreground "#5a5b5a" :background "#292b2b") t) ; directive
     (3 '(:foreground "#81a2be" :background "#292b2b") t) ; kind
     (4 '(:foreground "#c5c8c6") t))) ; title
  t)
```

Here is an example of the overall result:

[image]

Comment: Do you know what I could do if I want a footnote in the special org block title, ie: #+ATTR_LATEX: :options {In [fn:1] it is stated:} #+BEGIN_alertblock This clearly indicates that the use of an FIR model ... #+END_alertblock [fn:1] Subspace-Based System, 1996 Here the footnote is not resolved. If I use the subsectioning it works: *** In [fn:1] it is stated: :B_alertblock: :PROPERTIES: :BEAMER_env: alertblock :END: This clearly indicates that the use of an FIR model ... *** :B_ignoreheading: :PROPERTIES: :BEAMER_env: ignoreheading :END: [fn:1] Subspace-Based System, 1996 Which transl